# Image is not showing any RGB color

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to download about 200 images using Sentinel-2 but when I open them in ArcMap, RGB color is not showing and its showing as blank image. This is happening with all of my images. The code I used for downloading images is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e5a75c94fd5a96dbec7c4916dcbf38f

But the images are like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't convert DN to Reflectance, use visualization parameters with scale factor:

```
var visualization = {
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
```

Comment: I don't want to visualize it in gee. I'm asking after the image is downloaded, its showing blank as in attached image. I have also changed symbology in arcmap but no rgb image

Comment: Ah, compute statistics or use custom stretch with min: 0, max: 3000.

Comment: Computed statistics but nothing improved.

Comment: Set custom stretch then, the rasters are ok, the problem symbology setup

Comment: Still same as in the attached image. I don't know why its not showing anything in arcmap

Comment: I noticed that you commented the line that maps the maskS2clouds function to the image collection. If you left that mapping out, then your values are integers, as @aldo_tapia commented. If so, then you need to set your visualization parameters in ArcGIS correctly. If you _did_ use the masks2clouds function, then you have float values and you should change that in the parameters to the batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive function (currently using "int16").